# Don't use layer cache, but do use mount-cache when using docker+buildkit

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

When using buildkit, using the docker cli frontend, I sometimes do not want to use layer-cache, but do want to rely on the newer mount-cache type.

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=...
```

However running `docker build --no-cache` seemingly disables both.

Is there a way to choose such that only mount-cache is used during a rebuild ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the layer cache?

Comment: to force a package manager to update to its latest state,  but in this case, with all the packages which have not changed still in the mount cache.

Comment: This is also useful to measure time saving when implementing caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack around it by starting the Dockerfile with a layer that will always change, invalidating all following cached layers.

An ARG with always-changing values will do. E.g:

```
FROM whatever
ARG CACHE_EPOCH
# ... etc
```

```
docker build --pull --build-arg CACHE_EPOCH=$(date +%s)
```

(I have a very similar need https://stackoverflow.com/a/72993502/11715259)

Comment: On windows: `--build-arg CACHE_EPOCH="%time%"`